# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

**persistence.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

 <persistence-unit name="xyz" transaction-type="JTA">

  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <class>com......</class>
 </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

 <bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
     <property name="username" value="yyy" />
     <property name="password" value="yyy" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="xyz" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="true" /> -->
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="theDao" class="com.cin.the.dataaccess.dao.the.TheJPA">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
 </bean>
```

the error i get is

```
[PersistenceUnit: xyz] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

can any one tell me the mistake

Comment: there must be more for the error - a stacktrace for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem was that the entites was not generated properly. so at the end of the stacktrace it was giving this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com......date type: object
```

once the entity was generated correctly the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

[Someone answered here](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=177941&postcount=2):

> If you define your persistence unit with the JTA transaction type, you
>   need also to define your datasource inside the jta-data-source
>   attribute.

Try adding this to your `ApplicationContext.xml`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="your-jndi-name" />
```

and the following to `<persistence-unit>` element in `persistence.xml`:

```
<jta-data-source>your-jndi-name</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: i am not using the jndi connection.. i am giving the connection configuration settings in the ApplicationContext.xml as dataSource

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have mapped your domain object datatype to be java.lang.Object. map it to more specific like a String, int, long...